# Get new instances of ZF2 ViewHelper/Form/etc

Tags: zend-framework2

Is it possible to get a new instance of a ZF2 View Helper, Form and the like on each call?

My main issue at the moment is with view helpers. Each time I call the helper I need it to be constructed as need to have new objects passed into it but it doesn't matter what config I have it only ever passes through the factory the once.
With that the objects which are generated via the factory are the same for each instance, which Is not what I'm wanting.

I've tried various configs such as setting the view helper as shared, but that hasn't helped.

This is my config as it currently stands;

```
/**
 *
 */
'view_helpers' => array(
    'shared' => array(
        'notes' => false,
        ), 
    'factories' => array(
        'notes' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Factory\ViewHelper\Notes',
        'note'  => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Factory\ViewHelper\Note',
        )
    ),
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Since you mention them in the question are your custom view helpers using other view helpers, such as form helpers which are themselves persisting state? If so, you'll likely need to add all of them to the `shared` array as well as your custom view helper.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

The `shared` config key is to mark the services that require a new instance to be created each time you request them.

The problem however, is that you have to use the service *name*.

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'shared' => [
        'notes' => false,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        'notes' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Factory\ViewHelper\Notes',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've been playing around with the config and just copied and pasted what there without checking. The config you suggested is what tried.

Comment: This is working for me. The problem could be with the factory or the 'notes' helper. Update your question with them.

Comment: Also double check you have actually defined a namespace at the top of `module.config.php` (e.g. `namespace MyModule;`).

Comment: I've got the namespace defined. For now, I've had to create an alias in order to use the functionality as I'd like to for now.